# How can I implement this function with JK flip-flop + NAND gates?

Tags: digital-logic, logic-gates, counter

I need to design a mod-5 up/down counter with control input x. When x = 0 it will count down, and when x = 1 it will count up. I'm allowed to use only a JK flip-flop and NAND gates. Complement of x is not available.

I thought a 3-bit number which is ABC. I wrote the table and I created a Karnaugh map for A which is the first digit. I am stuck there because the function I got for A is (A'.B'.C'.x'+B.C.x) and I couldn't find any way to implement this function with the given gates.

The final step must be in the JK flip-flop to make it synchronize with the clock.

I have been thinking for two hours about this. Can you give me a way to implement this function?

Note: Complements of A, B, and C are available and logic levels 1 and 0 are available.

Comment: *One* NAND gate?

Comment: no, multiple nand gates and jk flip flops can be used.

Comment: Well, just with NAND gates you can implement *anything*. NAND gates are functionally complete. Can you think how you implement NOT with NAND? Hint: Not(A)=NAND(A,A).

Comment: Hint:Moore state machine

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule the following is true..

1)  U' = U NAND U

This can be built from one NAND gate.

2)  U OR V = U' NAND V' = (U NAND U) NAND (V NAND V)

This can be built from two 2-input NAND gates.

3)  U AND V = (U NAND V)' = (U NAND V) NAND (U NAND V)

This can be built from two 2-input NAND gates.



We can apply the above rules over and ove to the equation below.

(A'.B'.C'.x'+B.C.x) 

A' = A NAND A
B' = B NAND B
C' = C NAND C
X' = X NAND X

D = A' NAND B' (intermediate signal)
E = C' NAND X' (intermediate signal)

D' = D NAND D (which is A'.B')
E' = E NAND E (which is C'.x')

F = D' NAND E' (intermediate signal)
F' = F NAND F (which is A'.B'.C'.x')

G  = B NAND C (intermediate signal)
G' = G NAND G (which is B.C)
H  = G' NAND X (intermediate signal)
H' = H NAND H (which is B.C.x)

I = F NAND H (which is A'.B'.C'.x'+B.C.x)

Expanding the whole thing gives...

A'.B'.C'.x'+B.C.x = F NAND H

A'.B'.C'.x'+B.C.x = (D' NAND E') NAND (G' NAND X)

A'.B'.C'.x'+B.C.x = ((D NAND D) NAND (E NAND E)) NAND ((G NAND G) NAND X)

A'.B'.C'.x'+B.C.x = (((A' NAND B') NAND (A' NAND B')) NAND ((C' NAND X') NAND (C' NAND X'))) NAND (((B NAND C) NAND (B NAND C)) NAND X)

A'.B'.C'.x'+B.C.x = ((((A NAND A) NAND (B NAND B)) NAND ((A NAND A) NAND (B NAND B))) NAND (((C NAND C) NAND (X NAND X)) NAND ((C NAND C) NAND (X NAND X)))) NAND (((B NAND C) NAND (B NAND C)) NAND X)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fAaptn.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: I don't feel like editing your answer lol... but if you're just curious for next time, try utilizing the `\cdot` \$\cdot\$ for AND and `\overline{X}` \$\overline{X}\$ to negate something. I wouldn't blame you for adding all of the Mathjax for this...